# Getting 404 error at http://xf2-tutorial.localhost/1234 using zend

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I'm trying follow the **Getting started: A skeleton application** of zend framework at this [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html). I'm using xampp as a host.

### What I did

following the documentation, I downloaded the .zip skeleton tutorial file in [github](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) and put the extracted file in this path

> C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\zf2-tutorial

using gitbash composer I run `composer install` directly from the given path and successfully installed its dependencies.

in `httpd.conf` file I added this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
       ServerName localhost </VirtualHost> <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/practice/zf2-tutorial/public
     ServerName xf2-tutorial.localhost
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/practice/zf2-tutorial/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>  </VirtualHost>
```

and in `host` file in this location `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\` I added this

> 127.0.0.1 xf2-tutorial.localhost

After restarting apache, and visit this

> http://xf2-tutorial.localhost/

in the browser it render successfully the index.page but when I try to visit

> http://xf2-tutorial.localhost/1234

I get 404 error, what I did, I checked tha .htaccess if correct, this was the content of the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

I added this,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

But still I get 404 error

Any Idea, what to do with it?

Comment: What are you expecting to see instead? Is the error an Apache 404, or is it coming from ZF?

Comment: I figure out already that I'm not routing to a controller